# bash + awk + grep.... parse and save variable

Tags: bash, awk, grep

i have a config file....

```
# LogicalUnit section
[LogicalUnit1]
  LUN0 /mnt/extent0 64MB
[LogicalUnit2]
  LUN0 /mnt/extent1 64MB
[LogicalUnit3]
  LUN0 /mnt/extent4 10MB
```

i need to read field 2 and 3 from all lines that start with LUN into variables, and execute a shell comman using those variables

so... LUN0, i read field 2 and field 3, into a variable

```
/mnt/extent4 10MB
```

so say

```
A=/mnt/extent4
B=10MB
var1=A
var2=B

exec command -s $B $A
```

i get the logic, yet cannot figure out how to loop the file, read the 2 fields and pass them back to bash. Much helps appreciated, ive spent two days with bash grep and awk... im still not there. thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bash and would be better suited at [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: @ColeJohnson to parse and execute a file perfectly suits in [so].

Comment: @fedorqui the key words were **better suited**.

Comment: What about `eval \`sed -n -e"s/^ *LUN[0-9] \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\).*$/exec command -s \1 \2/p" test.txt\``  or  `eval \`grep "^ *LUN" test.txt | awk '{print "exec command -s "$2" "$3}'\``

Comment: every time i googled for sample information on bash, awk, sed, and grep 99% of the hits were stack overflow urls.... so i thought it would be appropriate. Im curious what one considers suitable.

Answer (score 4):

With awk you can get the values:

```
$ awk '/LUN/ {print $2, $3}' a
/mnt/extent0 64MB
/mnt/extent1 64MB
/mnt/extent4 10MB
```

And then pipe to process:

```
$ awk '/LUN/ {print $2, $3}' a | while read a b
> do
> echo "this is $a and this is $b"
> echo "exec $a $b"
> done
this is /mnt/extent0 and this is 64MB
this is /mnt/extent1 and this is 64MB
this is /mnt/extent4 and this is 10MB
```

Or

```
$ awk '/LUN/ {print $2, $3}' a | while read a b; do echo "this is $a and this is $b"; echo "exec $a $b"; done
this is /mnt/extent0 and this is 64MB
exec /mnt/extent0 64MB
this is /mnt/extent1 and this is 64MB
exec /mnt/extent1 64MB
this is /mnt/extent4 and this is 10MB
exec /mnt/extent4 10MB
```

Or even better ([thanks kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414978/bash-awk-grep-parse-and-save-variable/19415013?noredirect=1#comment28781377_19415013)):

```
awk '/LUN/ {system("command " $2 $3);}'
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the existence of `system()` in `awk`. Updating to reflect so, thanks!

Comment: could i stack a system("command " $2 $3); system("command " $3); for each ?? i like the one liner, its clean and short.

Comment: the larger issue appears to be not initialization, but reinitializing a lun thats already live and creating a second instance

Comment: can i double stack to read the prior line with variable as $c also ?awk '/UnitInquiry/ {print $2, $3}' $ctld_config | while read c ; do
awk '/LUN/ {print $2, $3}' $ctld_config | while read a b ; do

Comment: or would it be awk '/LUN/ {print $2, $3}' '/UnitInquiry/ {print $2}' /etc/ctld.conf | while read a b c; do ??

Comment: @user2888268 both options are fine, what you need to do in the `while read` way is to add a line `command $a $b` or whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `awk` followed by `xargs`

```
awk '$1~/LUN/ {print $3, $2}' file | xargs -n 1 command -s
```

Output of `awk`

```
64MB /mnt/extent0
64MB /mnt/extent1
10MB /mnt/extent4
```

Use of `xargs` with `-n 1` (maximum one argument at a time) will execute following set of commands

```
command -s 64MB /mnt/extent0
command -s 64MB /mnt/extent1
command -s 10MB /mnt/extent4
```

Answer (score 2):

A while loop and a read command:

```
while IFS= read -r f1 f2 f3; do
    if [[ $f1 == LUN* ]]; do
        some command with $f2 and $f3
    fi
done < input.file
```